# Why do my photos flash on my iphone ?

Tags: iphone

When looking at photos on google images or on facebook, the photos flash like a screen shot. I just got a new phone and it is doing this. I had an old iphone and this happened too. I have no idea if its a virus but my phone is only 2 weeks old. Its very annoying. help.

Comment: Are you using the built in Safari browser, or some other app(s)?

Comment: I use Safari but I also use the facebook app...both show photos flashing. Its like someone is taking a screenshot and say someone on facebook uploaded 6 photos and you can see them like an album, only 1 or a few of them will flash so its very random

Comment: Take a photo with the built-in camera and then view the image in the Photos app. Report back with your findings.

Comment: Did you restore a backup from your previous iPhone? It could be a software error that you "restored" on your new iPhone.

Comment: My old iphone did it as well. Then I bought a new one that the photos didnt flash for a week and then out of no where, it started again. Its very weird to say the least. With 2 phones doing it,..I cant find a pattern to point a finger too other than, a virus. I did open a document from my email so not sure if that is why.....

Comment: IconDameon, what would I report back?What would I be looking for? Is there something other than a photo image..?

Comment: Jules, the photos were flashing within a week of the new purchase. Then Iphone did an upgrade IOS...and the photos still flash. I have only own the phone for 2 weeks but my other phone did this for years. I just ignored it. I purposedly, chose another apple ID just in case I had a virus...and I did open a document from gmail that I had on my computer....so I think maybe a virus caused it...but the screen shot flash is so random...its doesnt seem like an error. Like most of the photos that flash are people faces...not buildings or animals, etc.,

Comment: I did do a search on this issue...and havent found one thread that offered and answer from apple